# Calling a Stored Procedure in MySQL Workbench having an OUT Parameter

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've been using TOAD for MySQL because I'm a convert from Oracle. I'm trying to find the time it takes to execute a procedure that calls one function. It is a very straight forward stored procedure except it has an `OUT` parameter:

```
PROCEDURE TESTME (OUT dTEST DOUBLE)
```

I decided to try out MySQL Workbench GUI.
How can I call this?
When I try `CALL TESTME` I get a 1318 error- Incorrect number of args.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to declare a variable to hold the out parameter first:

```
DECLARE @dummy DOUBLE;
CALL TESTME(@dummy);
```

ETA: I think actually declaring the variable is optional.  Just the `CALL` statement without the `DECLARE` should work.

Comment: This gives an error on DECLARE Keyword : syntax error, Unexpected DECLARE_SYM